# how do i sort this custom arraylist in java , in descending order of the number of boxes packed

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, compareto

this is my first class for the Crackerpacker,i have created another class for the arraylist and then added all these cracker packers to that arraylist , now i want to sort the arraylist in descending order of number of boxes packed by the CrackerPackers

```
public class CrackerPacker {
      private   String name;
      private int numberOfBoxes;

      public CrackerPacker (String name, int numberOfBoxes){
           this.name = name;
           this.numberOfBoxes = numberOfBoxes;
      }

        public int getNumberOfBoxes() {
            return numberOfBoxes;
        }

        public void setNumberOfBoxes(int numberOfBoxes) {
            this.numberOfBoxes = numberOfBoxes;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        enter code here
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CrackerPacker{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", numberOfBoxes=" + numberOfBoxes +
                    '}';
        }
        public double getwage() {
          if ( numberOfBoxes < 51 ) {
              return numberOfBoxes * 1.15;
          }
          else {
              double wage = (57.5 + ((numberOfBoxes - 50) * 1.25));
              return wage;
```

This is the second class in which i have created an arraylist to add all the crackerpacker objects in it
this arraylist i want sort in descending order of the number of boxes packed by the CrackerPackers

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Common {
    public static ArrayList<CrackerPacker> lectures = new ArrayList<>();

    int sum = 0;
    int boxes = 0;

    public int totalWage() {
        for (int i = 0; i < lectures.size(); i++) {
            sum += lectures.get(i).getwage();
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public int totalBoxes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < lectures.size(); i++){
            boxes += lectures.get(i).getNumberOfBoxes();

        }
    return boxes;
```

This my main method , i want sort the array list in descending roder of the number of boxes packed by the objects , please show me how can do it

```
  import java.util.Collections;

  public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CrackerPacker steve = new CrackerPacker("STEVE", 127);
        CrackerPacker gary = new CrackerPacker("Gary", 103);
        CrackerPacker tony = new CrackerPacker("tony", 473);
        CrackerPacker saad = new CrackerPacker("Saad", 129);
        CrackerPacker rubiya = new CrackerPacker("rubiya", 117);

        Common common = new Common();

        Common.lectures.add(steve);
        Common.lectures.add(gary);
        Common.lectures.add(tony);
        Common.lectures.add(saad);
        Common.lectures.add(rubiya);


        for ( CrackerPacker element : Common.lectures) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
        System.out.println(common.totalWage());
        System.out.println(common.totalBoxes());
```

i think i have use the compareto method but i dont knwo how to implement it

Answer (score 2):

The below compares the `numberOfBoxes` of the passed `CrackerPacker` with that of the current objects. This will have the effect of sorting it in descending order.

```
public class CrackerPacker implements Comparable<CrackerPacker> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(CrackerPacker c) {
        return Integer.compare(c.numberOfBoxes, this.numberOfBoxes);
    }
}
```

From the javadoc,

> Compares this object with the specified object for order.  Returns a
>        negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>        than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Hence, when comparing two CrackerPacker objects we are reversing the Integer compare check to achieve a descending ordering.

Example: Comparing 5 and 10, we are comparing 10 with 5 and hence *Integer.compare* returns 1 (since 10 > 5). But from outside comparison, we are stating that the first object is *bigger* than the second and hence it will appear after the second (..10....5...). This sorts the list in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

The following expression will help

```
Collections.sort(Common.lectures, (Comparator< CrackerPacker >) (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.getNumberOfBoxes(), o2.getNumberOfBoxes()));
```